# Dotfuscator removing the digital signature from dll

Tags: dll, certificate, digital-signature, dotfuscator

I have a .net windows application in which I am using dotfuscator to prevent reverse engineering. So my dll's are protected. The new requirement was to sign the dll's. But when I do sign the dll, my signing does not happen when I do dotfuscation where as when I remove the dlls from dotfuscated xml, then the digital signing of dlls happens. Any idea or solution how I can tackle this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dotfuscator works by disassembling and re-assembling your assemblies (`.dll` files). You will need to re-sign your assemblies after Dotfuscator re-assembles them.

If you're using Dotfuscator Professional, Dotfuscator can do some of this signing automatically. See the User Guide for instructions to re-apply [Authenticode signing](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/protection_build_and_debug.html#pctoc-re-signing-obfuscated-assemblies-with-authenticode) and [Strong Name signing](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/protection_build_and_debug.html#pctoc-obfuscating-strong-named-assemblies).

If you're using the free Dotfuscator Community included with Visual Studio, you will need to re-sign your assemblies using tools like [signtool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) and [sn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool).

(I am a developer on the Dotfuscator team and am answering this question in that capacity.)